# Sound disappearing ("Dummy output") on any kernel above 5.15, Dell XPS 17

Tags: drivers, sound, dell, alsa, pipewire

so I'm regularly having some sound problems with my Dell on kernel updates, but the latest one (when pipewire was introduced) completely baffles me, as I really have no clue what to do any longer.

Yes - it works fine on the older kernels, but I can't stay on 5.15 forever because of other features. Distro-wise, I've tried to make it work on 22.04, 22.10 and now 23.04, but no luck with any of them.

Here are the diagnostics, and below is the list of things I've tried.

inxi -SMA:

```
> System:   Host: a-buntu Kernel: 6.4.2-1-liquorix-amd64 arch: x86_64
> bits: 64
>     Desktop: GNOME v: 44.2 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster) Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Precision 5750 v: N/A
>     serial: <superuser required>   Mobo: Dell model: 0FR8C2 v: A00 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell
>     v: 1.24.0 date: 03/14/2023 Audio:   Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel   Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition
> Audio driver: snd_hda_intel   Sound API: ALSA v:
> k6.4.2-1-liquorix-amd64 running: yes   Sound Server-1: PipeWire v:
> 0.3.71 running: yes
```

pactl list short:

```
1   libpipewire-module-rt   {
            nice.level    = -11
            #rt.prio      = 88
            #rt.time.soft = -1
            #rt.time.hard = -1
        }   
2   libpipewire-module-protocol-native      
3   libpipewire-module-profiler     
5   libpipewire-module-metadata     
7   libpipewire-module-spa-device-factory       
9   libpipewire-module-spa-node-factory     
11  libpipewire-module-client-node      
13  libpipewire-module-client-device        
15  libpipewire-module-portal       
16  libpipewire-module-access   {
            # access.allowed to list an array of paths of allowed
            # apps.
            #access.allowed = [
            #    /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session
            #]

            # An array of rejected paths.
            #access.rejected = [ ]

            # An array of paths with restricted access.
            #access.restricted = [ ]

            # Anything not in the above lists gets assigned the
            # access.force permission.
            #access.force = flatpak
        }   
17  libpipewire-module-adapter      
19  libpipewire-module-link-factory     
21  libpipewire-module-session-manager      
536870912   module-always-sink      
54  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo    PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
54  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo.monitor    PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
63  54  62  PipeWire    float32le 1ch 25Hz
33  PipeWire    pipewire
31  PipeWire    pipewire-media-session
32  PipeWire    pipewire-media-session
59  PipeWire    xdg-desktop-portal
60  PipeWire    gsd-media-keys
61  PipeWire    gnome-shell
62  PipeWire    gnome-control-center
70  PipeWire    gnome-terminal-server
71  PipeWire    chrome
72  PipeWire    pactl
48  alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1  alsa
49  alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3  alsa
```

aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio":

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
    Subsystem: Dell Comet Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at 609b218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 609b100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 73000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
```

cat /proc/asound/modules:

```
 0 snd_hda_intel
 1 snd_hda_intel
```

lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel:

```
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         204800  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_core          131072  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               192512  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                   139264  23 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_seq_oss,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"

```
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input14
input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input15
input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input16
input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input17
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
```

What I've tried was (update number 3):

1. Blacklisting snd-intel-dspcfg as well as snd_soc_skl
2. Killing, restarting, deleting and reinstalling pipewire, sof, alsa, ucm
3. Adding option *snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0* to both modprobe and grub
4. *touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio* followed by a restart
5. Removing timidity
6. Adding *options snd-hda-intel model=generic* and *options snd-usb-audio index=-2* to modprobe
7. Installing linux-modules-extra
8. Looking into snd-hda-intel driver dependencies (all were installed)

That last thing was actually the only thing that lead to any change, as the "Dummy output" in the Settings changed to "HDMI/Display port" (connecting to my computer via HDMI or Bluetooth produces sounds), but that change had no effect on anything else.

I've been reading dozens of topics here for two days now, but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bump please? I don't know where else to look...

Comment: Updated with more things I've tried

Comment: Update 4: tried literally every kernel above 5.15, still no luck. Maybe the trick is in something that changed at that time?

Comment: Update 5: more new things that I've tried.

Comment: Add `journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"` output

Comment: @R A   added, thank you